# Cant scroll down i pad view in bootstrap accordion tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, bootstrap-4, frontend, web-frontend

[cant view the bottom details of the selected card class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Pr6.png)
I created the bootstrap accordion view and made it responsive for mobile when I opened it in I pad view I cant view the bottom part of the selected card and I cant scroll down to see the bottom part of the selected accordion card.